# I'm having trouble creating a cleanup function for garbage collection [example inside]

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to have a global cleanup function, and pass the MovieClip or TextField for removal. I want to remove the clip without referencing the clip directly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var clip:Sprite = new Sprite();
clip.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1)
clip.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100)
clip.graphics.endFill()
clip.name = "clip"
addChild(clip);

cleanup(clip)

function cleanup(mc):void {
    removeChild(mc.parent.getChildByName(mc.name));
    mc = null

    // clip is removed and traces as [object Sprite]
    trace(clip)

    //
    addChild(clip);
    removeChild(clip)
    clip = null

    // clip is removed and traces as null.
    trace(clip)
}
```

Here is the FLA (Flash cs4): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4725599/test-cs4.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of scope. I'll try to explain what you're doing:

```
function cleanup(mc):void {
    removeChild(mc.parent.getChildByName(mc.name)); // removes the "clip" sprite
    mc = null; // nulls the local var "mc", which essentially does nothing

    addChild(clip);     // re-add the "clip" sprite
    removeChild(clip)   // remove the "clip" sprite
    clip = null;        // null the "clip" sprite, removing the last reference to the memory allocated for the sprite
}
```

Basically, when you create your `Sprite`, you're allocating the memory needed for a `Sprite` and assigning it to the `clip` variable. Your sprite now has one reference to it.

You then add it to the stage. This creates a new reference, so your sprite now has 2 references. That's it.

The `mc` variable in the `cleanup()` function is a temporary variable - they're cleaned up after the function exits so you don't need to worry about it. Basically to tag your `Sprite` for garbage collection, you need to remove the 2 references to it: the `clip` variable, and the stage. So you simply need to do:

```
clip.parent.removeChild( clip );
clip = null;
```

And it's done.

Check out that: http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3 (disclaimer: my site) which should give you a good explanation of how memory works in as3

**Edit**
Normally you would work this based on classes. In all my classes, I implement a `destroy()` function that I can call to clean up the class (remove children, event listeners, any references to other objects etc). For the code calling `destroy()`, it doesn't care what the object does or how it works, it just know that afterwards the object is good for garbage collection.

As a general principle, the object creating something is also responsible for destroying it.

Comment: This all makes sense, but what happens if I try to pass a MovieClip/Sprite through the function? I guess I could setup a whole bunch of conditionals to see if the clip being passed != null. There should be a better way to do that?

Comment: I updated my answer with a few other points. For specifics, you do your checking if it'll throw an Error. For example, I never call `removeChild()` without first checking if it has a parent.

Comment: making sure that whatever's passed to `cleanup()` all depends on the structure of your code. If you have well defined states (init, play, destroy), then you shouldn't have this problem. If you're trying to cleanup the same object twice, then you've a problem with structure. That said, adding a check never hurts ;) It helps for all of us that run debug players in their main browser

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that what you're doing - removing the display object from the parent's display list - could be not enough.
To be eligible for the garbage collector, every listener assigned to that object must be removed too. And, if the object is referenced elsewhere, for example in an array, it is not going to be correctly garbage collected.
What I'm saying is that probably trying to write a function for the GC is not that easy. I usually dispose every object manually.
Hope it helps!